# How to change Theme dynamically in Android for Different level of API

Tags: android, datepicker

in application i have set the  `android:minSdkVersion="8"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` now i want to change the theme of the application depending upon the android version. like if api level is 8 this `Datepicker` should appear

[image: API Level 8 Datepicker]

And if the level is above 11 `Datepicker` should appear

[image]

Comment: thats depends on what os-version the target comes. another think, you can  obtain these system specific themes from the internet (https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) and set it in your code. takem notice you need the ui components from sdk < 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this dude :)

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            System.out.println("mdpi current version is =="+ currentapiVersion); 

    if (  currentapiVersion < 11)
        {

         // your condition code for date picker 
    }

    else
    {
      // your condition code for date picker 
    }
```

Your directory structure could look like this:

```
res/
  values/
    styles.xml
  values-v11/
    styles.xml
```

The contents of res/values/styles.xml would be something like:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    ...
  </style>
</resources>
```

And the contents of res/values-v11/styles.xml would be something like:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    ...
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: what y so what u get in currentapiVersion

Comment: same out put in both version

Comment: date theme is not changing

Comment: may be u didnt something wrong because this same is working for me at my side

Comment: ok if i take new project it is working in old project when i created the folder it is not working thanks, but i want to know what mistake m doing..........

Comment: cant understand what u exactly want to ask ??

Comment: ok it's working when i take new project but in old(previous) project when i created the folder as you mentioned it is not working thanks, but i want to know what mistake m doing..........

Answer (score 1):

Create your own theme, and make it extend a different theme depending on API level, for example if you put the theme in the folder `values-v11` it will will work for api level 11 and above. I hope I made myself clear

Answer (score 1):

Use different values folder according to your api need. Use `values-v11` folder to change theme above api level 11 like this :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
```

Place this `style.xml` in values-v11 folder.

Comment: If you need any help to implement this then tell me.

Comment: it is showing error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Dark'.

Comment: no i tried to add `<item name="android:dateTextAppearance">@android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar</item>` it is showing error Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - android:dateTextAppearance requires API level 11 (current 
  min is 8).....

Comment: have you add any library which have this thing.

Comment: the folder name was wrong which u have written values-11 and the values-v11 is correct that is why i am getting that error thanks

Comment: then rename your folder name and check this.